# Alert on locked question comment vote incorrect

Tags: bug, comments, flags, historical-lock

When one tries to vote on a comment on a historically locked question, one gets the alert pop up of:

> [image]

*However*, it *is* possible to flag comments.  For the SE types who can dig beyond the ability of mortals, see the date of the flags on [the comments on this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/940/what-are-your-favorite-version-control-systems/4885#4885).

Please change the wording of the alert to match the current functionality. One could instead change the functionality to match the alert, though in doing so it does become more difficult for regular users to work to curate the content (yes, all that about historical lock being preserved as is forever and whatnot... but one shouldn't need to go to meta to ask mods to clean up comments suggesting the mutilation of corpses).

Comment: Wow, wtf? Did I miss something? "Possible dupe" message is now capitalized!